# Rank of Jacobian Matrix for the Stereographic Projection

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, spheres, stereographic-projections

With the definition $S^{n} = \{\ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\ | \ ||\mathbf{x}|| = 1\  \}$, and the function $\ f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to S^{n} \setminus \{ (0,...,0,1) \}$ defined by:

$f(\mathbf{u}) = \left( \ \frac{ 2 u_{1} }{  ||\mathbf{u}||^{2} + 1  },\ ...,\  \frac{ 2 u_{n} }{  ||\mathbf{u}||^{2} + 1  },\ \frac{  ||\mathbf{u}||^{2} - 1  }{  ||\mathbf{u}||^{2} + 1  } \ \right)$

I'm trying to show that the rank of the Jacobian matrix $\mathcal{J}$, is $n$ for all $\mathbf{u} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and I can't figure out how to do this.

After some annoying computations, I find that the matrix looks like:

$\mathcal{J}(\mathbf{u}) = \frac{1}{\left( ||\mathbf{u}||^2 + 1 \right)^{2}} \left[ \begin{matrix}
  \ 2 \left( ||\mathbf{u}||^2 + 1 \right) - 4 u_{1}^2 & - 2 u_{1} u_{2} & \cdots & - 2 u_{1} u_{n} \\
  - 2 u_{1} u_{2} & 2 \left( ||\mathbf{u}||^2 + 1 \right) - 4 u_{2}^2 & \cdots & - 2 u_{2} u_{n} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  - 2 u_{1} u_{n} & - 2 u_{2} u_{n} & \cdots & 2 \left( ||\mathbf{u}||^2 + 1 \right) - 4 u_{n}^2\  \\
  4 u_{1} & 4 u_{2} & \cdots & 4 u_{n}\  \\
 \end{matrix} \right]$

How do I proceed to show that $\mathrm{rank}(\mathcal{J}(\mathbf{u})) = n$ for all $\mathbf{u}$?

It's easy to see that $\mathcal{J}(\mathbf{0})$ has rank $n$. I have already proven that $f$ is a homeomorphism of class $C^{\infty}$, so I am wondering is there some result I can use that states that the rank remains $n$ in a neighbourhood of $\mathbf{0}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? Otherwise, how else can I prove this?

EDIT: I realize that I can row-reduce the matrix, but this seems tedious and I am looking for ways to avoid row-reducing

Comment: btw, you get a wrong Jacobian matrix

Comment: What is my error?

Comment: the coefficient should be -4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> DO NOT USE JACOBIAN MATRICES!

The stereographic projection $$s:S^{n}\setminus \{(0,...,0,1)\}\to \mathbb R^n: x=(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})\mapsto u= \frac {1}{1-x_{n+1}}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$$ is clearly $C^\infty$ and is the inverse of your map: $s=f^{-1}$.
Hence your map $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to S^{n} \setminus \{ (0,...,0,1) \}$ is a diffeomerphism and as such has rank $n$.

Comment: In my problem, I am trying to prove that $S^{n}$ is a manifold, and in my definition of a manifold, my professor has us to prove that the Jacobian of the coordinate patch has rank $n$. In defining a diffeomorphism, don't you need to assume that the function maps between manifolds? So my question is, am I allowed to say that $f^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism since I "don't know yet" that $S^{n}$ is a manifold?

Comment: The set $S^n$ is a **sub**manifold of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$: this is completely trivial because it is the zero locus of$ f(x)=\sum x_i^2-1$ and $grad(f)(x)\neq0$ for $x\in S^n$. The notion of submanifold of $\mathbb R^k$ is just advanced calculus and is independent of the much more advanced rigmarole about atlasses and their compatible charts :-) Of course if you insist on proving that your matrix has maximal rank go ahead, but that will be a dreary  algebra exercise with zero geometrical content. However I agree that it is always more prudent to do what your professor wants...

Answer (score 2):

you can do Gaussian elimination to compute the rank